# Unbounded Stack

Tags: function, stack

I've got a question. How can I implement a function inside a certain struct, which is going to remove all the elements(values) from the Unbounded Stack which are lower than the value given in the parameter by the user ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I have got two structures, first one is a Stack, and inside it I have to declare a function which finds values lower than the parameter given by the user and deletes it. Im actually stuck in the idea of implementing this kind of function. It should look like a clear(); function or probably erase(); but I'm not sure if it would be correct to add a parameter in the function that Im trying to declare